# Launch multiple EC2 instances with name convention

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to launch multiple (for example, 10) EC2 instances following the name convention:

name = **[testcluster]db{1..10}**

In result, I want the following names of the instances:

**[testcluster]db1**

**[testcluster]db2**

**...**

**[testcluster]db10**

Is it possible in the web GUI?

Comment: Not possible. Launch and modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest capability is the [AMI Launch Index Value](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#AMI-launch-index-examples), which is a unique value for each instance launched in a **Reservation** (which is the name given to a group of instances launched at the same time).

You could write a User Data script that:

- Retrieves the AMI Launch Index via `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-launch-index`
- Retrieves the Instance ID via `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
- Calls `aws ec2 create-tags` to add a `Name` tag to the instance, using the AMI Launch Index to number the instance

Put it all together and you get this command:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resource `curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` --tags Key=x,Value=db`curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-launch-index`
```

It will self-tag an instance with the instance name and number (eg db1).

Note: The first instance is actually number zero.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible via GUI but is possible if you launch instances via CLI, then you just change tags using your script.