# How do I launch multiple EC2 instances to run a program with different parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, ec2-ami, ec2-api-tools

I am running a program which takes in certain parameters. Because the program will run for a long time, I am thinking to launch multiple EC2 instances such that I can run this program with different parameters in parallel. Ideally, I would like to

1. Launch multiple EC2 instances (say 10 of them) with *identical* setup. I understand that a single instance could have many cores and I am using one with 96 cores but that is simply not enough.
2. Schedule the instances to run my program with *different* parameters and save the result to certain github repository
3. The instances can shut down automatically once the program is finished, or I can shut down all the instances at once conveniently (to avoid unnecessary costs)

I have looked around and I found

1. It seems like "Terraform" is a tool that can be used to launch multiple EC2 instances see [here](https://medium.com/@mudasirhaji/how-to-launch-multiple-ec2-instances-in-one-go-using-simple-and-easy-terraform-code-3753489bdd8b) for example. But I don't know how to make sure the instances have identical setup, and how to tune the parameters for different instances
2. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766136/launch-multiple-ec2-instances-with-name-convention) talks about how to set up the instances with different names, but not sure if it can be used in my case to tune parameters

There are many similar questions/request as mine, but I couldn't find the solution for exactly my problem, so I would really appreciate if anyone can help! Thanks!

Comment: If your instances are able to communicate outside, you may register the tasks with parameters on a sheet outside, like github and let the instance to take the task and update the sheet

Comment: I recommend that you experiment with different instance types. You might think that the 96-core instance will provide the fastest processing, but it is twice the cost of a 48-core instance and 4 times the cost of a 24-core instance. You might find that your software cannot scale-up to take advantage of all cores, so do some experiments to figure out the most cost-effective instance type to use.

Comment: @Icarus I think communicating, grabbing and updating an external sheet seems quite complicated, and could result in race condition. I think there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I did check the usage of the cores via the "top" command, and it shows that all the cores are running 100% all the time. So I guess the cost is inevitable, but I definitely would like to avoid letting the instance sitting idle for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than specifying parameters when launching the instances, I would recommend a **'message queue' architecture**:

- Create an **Amazon SQS queue**
- **Send messages to the queue**, with each message representing some 'work' to be performed (that is, with the parameters for a particular task that needs to be done) -- each message could represent a small piece of work, or a large piece of work, it is up to you.
- **Launch your EC2 instances**, each with the same software and the same startup script
- After boot-up, the **startup script** on each instance runs a program that keeps looping. Inside the loop it should:

  - **Retrieve a message** from the SQS queue
  - **Perform the work** associated with the message
  - If no messages were available in the queue, the instance should **Terminate itself**

This architecture will automatically distribute work amongst the instances, with each instance grabbing more work when it needs it. It will also also work with any number of instances, but more instances will process the work in a shorter elapsed time.

See also: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: This seems like precisely the architecture I am looking for! I will search for how to use SQS, and maybe use Terraform in the 3rd step to launch EC2 instances. If you have more references/resources/examples, please let me know! Thanks1

Comment: You could also use an Auto Scaling group to launch multiple instances. If you want to keep them for continual processing, then Auto Scaling can also launch/terminate instances to match the available workload. (Do a search for SQS and Auto Scaling.)